# Funny byte[] count when downloading file

Tags: android, inputstream, androidhttpclient

I've got a funny result when downloading a file online using DefaultHttpClient.
The code is pasted here:

```
InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
int count=0;
byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
do {
    count++;
    int result = is.read(buf);
    if ( result < 0) {
        break;
    }
} while (!cancelDownload);
Log.e(TAG, "count:" + count);
is.close();
```

Although the download url is constant, the "count" can be a different number when downloading is completed.

And, I dont know why the file I got from the url is always what I want.

What might be happening with my downloading?

Comment: count represents the number of calls the `read`. but `read` can return any number of bytes, from 1 to 1024, and this count is returned in `result`. You want to use `count += result;`

Comment: Thank U!  The `result` is not always 1024 even if end of the file is not reached.  Your kind-heart helps me a lot!